# Jordan form of a nondiagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a matrix of order $4$ over $\Bbb C$ such that rank of A is $2$ and $A^3=A^2.$Suppose that A is not diagonalizable.Then prove that there exist a vector $v$ such that $Av\neq 0$ but $A^2v=0$

Since given matrix A is of rank $2$ and not diagonalizable using Jordan form we are getting characteristic polynomial as $x^4-x^3$ but I am not getting proof for existance of $v$ such that $Av\neq 0$ but $A^2v=0$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Since $A \in M(n, \Bbb C)$ nondiagonalizable, it must have a Jordan block of size $> 1$. If the corresponding eigenvalue is $\lambda \neq 0$, that Jordan block has rank $> 1$, so $A$ must have Jordan form
$$J_k(\lambda) \oplus 0_{n - k}, \qquad$$ for some $k > 1$, but $J_k(\lambda)^3 \neq J_k(\lambda)^2$, so $A^3 \neq A^2$---a contradiction. Thus, $A$ has a Jordan block $J_k(0)$ for some $k > 1$.

> **Additional hint** This already implies the existence of a $v$ such that $Av \neq 0$ but $A^2 v = 0$: If we write $A$ as $$A = P \pmatrix{J_k(0) & \\ & B} P^{-1}$$ for some direct sum $B$ of Jordan blocks and invertible matrix $P$, we see that $$v = P \pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\ \vdots\\0}$$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: I don't understand.Can u explain it in detail?

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question?